# UIActionSheet button's color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How can I change the color of UIActionSheet button's color?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**iOS 8 (UIAlertController)**

It's super simple to do if you're using a UIAlertController.  Simply change the tint color on the view of the UIAlertController.

```
[alertController.view setTintColor:[UIColor red];
```

**iOS 7 (UIActionSheet)**

I successfully change the text color by using this simple method.

```
- (void) changeTextColorForUIActionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet {
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    NSArray *actionSheetButtons = actionSheet.subviews;
    for (int i = 0; [actionSheetButtons count] > i; i++) {
        UIView *view = (UIView*)[actionSheetButtons objectAtIndex:i];
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)view;
            [btn setTitleColor:tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to run this **AFTER** you call

```
[actionSheet showInView];
```

If you call it before [showInView], all buttons but the cancel button will be colored.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: +1 for "Make sure to run this AFTER you call" for this quote.

Comment: Any idea why only in Portrait mode buttons are showing in red but in Landscape mode only cancel button is being colored.

Answer (score 7):

I have created child class UICustomActionSheet, which allows customize fonts, colors and images of buttons inside UIActionSheet. It is absolutely safety for appstore, you can find code of this class on next link:

https://github.com/gloomcore/UICustomActionSheet

Enjoy it!

Comment: Are you sure it's ok for the App Store? Anyway the result is great!

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I have used it on apps for Appstore. This class is using no private methods, so it's clear.

Comment: cancel button don't work if i used a number of otherbuttons and set its font runtime

Comment: Its not compatible with iOS 7 now.

Comment: Sorry for long waiting, I have pushed the latest changes to implement compatibility with iOs7 and flat design. So you can use it again.

Comment: According to the Apple docs, `UIActionSheet` should not be subclassed.

Comment: This message has appeared in version 7.0. UiActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed. But this change is not critical and it's not declined by the Apple team, because it use no private API and is not covered by any other restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without using undocumented API's, there is no official way to change the button's color on a UIActionSheet. You may be able to customize this if you subclass the UIActionSheet control.

See this example: http://blog.corywiles.com/customizing-uiactionsheet-buttons

Comment: Did you ever did this? Any sample code will be really helpful.

Comment: It's not difficult to change the button color and you can do it without using undocumented API's.

Comment: You should not subclass `UIActionSheet`. From the documentation: `UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.`

Answer (score 1):

We can use background images to do it. I think it is the easiest way.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actionsheet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 1"]; //Blue color
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 2"];
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:nil];
        [actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:2];
        [actionSheet setDestructiveButtonIndex:1];
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        UIButton *button = [[actionSheet subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
        UIImage *img = [button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];//[UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_button.png"];
        [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by using following code

> Apple `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol documentation
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
{
    for (UIView *_currentView in actionSheet.subviews) 
    {
        if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
        {    
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)_currentView;
            [button setTitleColor:YOUR_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```