# UIActionSheet Button color problem 

Tags: iphone, ios, button, uiactionsheet, uicolor

`What I am doing`

I am making a project with Actionsheet with three buttons in it.

`My problem`

I want that when I press button 1 .It should be highlighted in orange when I press the button..

It should only change when I press the button

suggestion please..

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActionSheet button's color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248400/uiactionsheet-buttons-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Evan Mulawski says in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248400/uiactionsheet-buttons-color):

> Without using undocumented API's, 
>   there is no official way to change the
>   button's color on a UIActionSheet. 
>   You may be able to customize this if
>   you subclass the UIActionSheet
>   control.
>
> See this example:
>   http://blog.corywiles.com/customizing-uiactionsheet-buttons

Comment: Don't copy another user's complete answer.  I've made the attribution very clear here, but you should still be able to find your own words to answer a question like this.