# Change color of specific UIActionSheet button?

Tags: button, colors, uiactionsheet

Does anyone know how to change the color of a specific UIActionSheet button to a green color?
I have googled this and have found nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248400/uiactionsheet-buttons-color

Comment: nope thats not my account. I'm still looking for an answer though!