# Custom colors to UIActionsheet buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

I want to make a `UIActionsheet`, with 4 buttons. One `button` is Cancel button, which is black in color. The rest of the 3 buttons should have a red background color, but they are not destructive buttons. Is it possible to make such an `actionsheet`?

Comment: Customizing the ActionSheet in your will be rejected from Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can customise the UIActionsheet..here are few links that may help you..I know this is late reply to your question,but may help someone..

http://blog.corywiles.com/customizing-uiactionsheet-buttons

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852402/1865424