# How to set UIActionSheet button color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I've been searching the internet and trying different thing but cannot seem to change the button title colour on my action sheet.

Here is the action sheet code.

```
- (void)showActionSheet
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Select Country"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

    for (NSString *listCountry in resultSet) [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:listCountry];

    [actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
}
```

I've tried this delegate but it does not work.

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4248450/1865424

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActionSheet button's color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248400/uiactionsheet-buttons-color)

Comment: i think Your code seems to be a perfect. put brekpoint  willPresentActionSheet is called or not

Comment: did you add UIActionSheet delegate in .h file?

Comment: Make sure you set, UIActionSheet delegate and set breakpoint on this method, - (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet, check whether this method getting called .

Comment: Yes UIActionSheetDelegate is in my .h file. I've tried breakpoints on every line within willPresentActionSheet and they all break out. So the method is been invoked. Just no colour changes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set, **UIActionSheet delegate** and set breakpoint on this method, 
**willPresentActionSheet**,
 check whether this method getting called .

If you have set delegate means, try this one

```
- (void) changeTextColorForUIActionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet {
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    NSArray *actionSheetButtons = actionSheet.subviews;
    for (int i = 0; [actionSheetButtons count] > i; i++) {
        UIView *view = (UIView*)[actionSheetButtons objectAtIndex:i];
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)view;
            [btn setTitleColor:tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}
```

Update:

1. https://github.com/seivan/SHActionSheetBlocks
2. https://github.com/ianb821/IBActionSheet

Comment: Is changeTextColorForUIActionSheet a delegate for actionSheet? If I copy this directly it does not execute. Yes UIActionSheetDelegate is in my .h file

Comment: Make sure to run that code, AFTER you call : [actionSheet showInView];

Comment: called [self changeTextColorForUIActionSheet:actionSheet]; after [actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];, still no luck

Comment: https://github.com/seivan/SHActionSheetBlocks ,  https://github.com/ianb821/IBActionSheet  just try this sample

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `UIActionSheetDelegate` and then you can use `willPresentActionSheet` delegate method

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```