# UiActionSheet bug in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uiactionsheetdelegate

i wanted to change buttons color in action sheet so i wrote this code

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
     for (UIView *_currentView in actionSheet.subviews) {
         if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)_currentView;
            button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"%@",@"ahmed");
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing happen although i made delegate to self and called UIActionSheetDelegate .
although i have 6 buttons ,i see as this function wasn't be called at all
what is the problem?????

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActionSheet button's color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248400/uiactionsheet-buttons-color)

Comment: this didnt work for me  too

Comment: I guess this changes can't be made in the willPresent. You need to make the customization before the call for presenting the action sheet.

Comment: i see other developers in other questions made it in stackoverflow

Comment: i made this also - (void) changeTextColorForUIActionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet {
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    NSArray *actionSheetButtons = actionSheet.subviews;
    for (int i = 0; [actionSheetButtons count] > i; i++) {
        UIView *view = (UIView*)[actionSheetButtons objectAtIndex:i];
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)view;
            [btn setTitleColor:tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}