# Button of UIAlertController changes its color on click. How to solve? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController with the `tintColor` orange but everytime I click on the Button it changes its color to blue (I guess the native color). How do i solve it?

```
let orange: UIColor = UIColor(red: 232.0/255, green: 121.0/255, blue: 23.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.view.tintColor = orange
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the `Bug` in `iOS 9.0`, see [apple Community bug reports](https://openradar.appspot.com/22209332), may be it fixed on `iOS 9.1`

for additional reference see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693369/uialertcontroller-tint-color-defaults-to-blue-on-highlight)