# Swift Alert Controller Color

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, tintcolor

I have an alert controller that I set to a new tint color with this line of code:

```
alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.59, blue: 0.59, alpha: 1.0)
```

The color does show correctly, but once the alert action is tapped, it changes back to the default blue color automatically. How can I make it so that the tint color does not change back to default. I have heard of the func tintColorDidChange() but I am unsure of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693369/uialertcontroller-tint-color-defaults-to-blue-on-highlight)

you should add the same code in `presentViewController` completion handler

```
presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { 
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.59, blue: 0.59, alpha: 1.0)
}
```