# How can I change the color of each button separately in UIAlertSheet?

Tags: objective-c, swift

How to replace the color of a single button in the AlertSheet?

[image]

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19191489/6371663) can help

Comment: You shouldn't, it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a destructive button you can change the style to destructive.

The below example will make delete red;

```
self.optionAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
```